# azure app service deployment on existing database

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sql-database

Hi guys i need assistance, I have an existing app service and database, I made changes on my ASP.NET application and deployed using azure deployment slots  and swapped, but my database isn't updating tables

Comment: What database are you using? Did you deploy via VS publish wizard? If you have db schema changes(added a table, or column etc), then you need to execute scripts to update your database.

Comment: the Azure Database for MySQL,  I used VS code to deploy

Comment: Are you using Entity Framework for db migration - what you mean by "tables aren't updating" - is your schema not updating? Or your app fails to update data in tables?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

In case of a database update, i.e, necessary scripts that need to be run in order to update the database schema for the new app version, you can use the **applicationInitialization** section of your **web.config**.

```
<system.webServer>  
  <applicationInitialization >  
    <add initializationPage="/init-script.php" hostName="xxxxxx.azurewebsites.net"/>  
  </applicationInitialization>  
<system.webServer>
```

The AppInit module will wait until this code completes before finishing the swap process which is basically allowing production traffic to the app.

Basic logic would be checking if the database is running the expected version and if not some other logic would be executed in sequence.